# Django templates filter order of execution

Tags: django, templates, filter

I would like to concatonate a Variable (identifier) with a string ("charge") and then use this as a key for a nested dict(attributes) this is my current code that fails:

```
attributes|valuebykey:"charge"|add:identifier
```

I think I need something like (basically changing the execution order):

```
attributes|valuebykey:("charge"|add:identifier)
```

But this syntax doesnt seem to work

flter: (just gets a value from a dict)

```
@register.filter
def valuebykey(d, k):
    try:
        ret = d.get(k)
        if ret is None:
            ret = ''
    except:
        ret = ''
    return ret
```

Any idea of how I can change the execution order, or have a filter with 3 separate args? or any other way I can find a value in a nested dict with a key thats a concatonation of a var and a string?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like the job of a template tag and not a filter! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
{% with key="charge"|add:identifier %}
    {{ attributes|valuebykey:key }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: ooh thats really nice, I see myself rewriting a fair chunk of template now... Thanks!